# SQL Select combine text to a selected item?

Tags: sql, t-sql, select

Hi I am trying to select and two ids from a database, the second one i would like to have text added to the result.

```
SELECT
   A.PractitionerId,
   'http://www.icuro.co.za/WebForms/Members/Appointments/AppointmentView.aspx?id=' + CAST(A.AppointmentId)
FROM
   Appointment AS A WITH (NOLOCK)
```

How would i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Seems like bad pratice to do this hardcoded in your query

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there, you need to tell `Cast` what to cast as:

```
SELECT
   A.PractitionerId,
   'http://www.icuro.co.za/WebForms/Members/Appointments/AppointmentView.aspx?id=' + CAST(A.AppointmentId as varchar(50))
FROM
   Appointment AS A WITH (NOLOCK)
```

Comment: Small things big difference. spend an hour on this :| , thanks saved my day.